# Open PDF in the PhoneGap App that is made in HTML and CSS

Tags: css, html, cordova

I have a strange problem with my iPad App in Phone Gap. The problem is that I have to open PDF document in my app through links and when I click the link which opens the PDF, it shows me the PDF document with no back link.

Hence, when I open the PDF document in my app through a link, it takes me to a dead end and there is no way I can go back to the main page of my app.

My question is that how can I have a Top-Bar, when I open a PDF which could take me back to my home page? Any internal element for the iPad may be?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using the In App Browser plugin.

If you're using a later Phonegap / Cordova version (2.8.0, 2.9.0 etc) it should come with it - nothing else to install.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

It will allow you to open the PDF in the a new 'window' that overlays your app. It has a 'Done' button that users can use to close it and return to your app when they are finished.

You would open the PDF using the In-App Browser, using something like this:

```
window.open('http://whitelisted-url.com/pdftoopen.pdf', '_blank');
```

I.e. the `_blank` option triggers the In-App Browser plugin. If you were to use `_system` instead it *might* open it in iBooks (just guessing there - not 100% sure if it would use iBooks).

Comment: Does someone happend to know why this is not working for me also? I use an iphone 4 and a cordova 3.

Comment: i dont get the "it should come with it". im using cordova 3.6 and yes you do have install `org.apache.cordova.inappbrowswer` for it to work. This worked great. Thanks!

Comment: @Gallwynmasc - For Cordova version 2.x, many of the plugins (including In App Browser) were included by default. With 3.x, the plugins are all optional, and you install the ones you want.

Answer (score 5):

Try prefixing `https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=` in the URL

like, `window.open('https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.example.com/example.pdf&embedded=true', '_blank', 'location=yes');`

Comment: This requires the user to sign in to Google Drive. Also make sure to encode the url parameter. Clever solution though.

Comment: I uploaded the PDF to Google Drive and set sharing to public, then shared the link. I don't believe this method requires the user to be logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to open any kind of documents from URL using following steps:

- install this plugin : cordova plugin add https://github.com/ti8m/DocumentHandler
- use this code :

  handleDocumentWithURL(function() { console.log('success'); }, function(error) { console.log('failure'); if (error == 53) { console.log('No app that handles this file type.'); } }, 'http://www.example.com/path/to/document.pdf');

It works for me both on Android and IOS. I used it for open **images** and **PDF** files.

**Android** : It opens files using system apps if available, otherwise it give an error, which you can handle.

**IOS** : It opens files in popup like view with Done button and Option button.

**It doesn't show your docs URL.**

Source is available here : https://github.com/ti8m/DocumentHandler

Answer (score 0):

Thanks asgeo1,

I solved it by using `window.open()`.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://12example.pdf', '_blank', 'location=no');"><img src="images/samplens.jpg" border="0" /></a>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, when using phonegap, window.open triggers the In App Browser plugin I mentioned ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using [WebIntent](https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent/blob/master/www/webintent.js)

as described [here](http://smartupit.blogspot.com/2014/07/cordova-download-and-open-file-on.html). The tricky part was to modify WebIntent.java to properly identify file type:

```
String type = obj.has("type") ? obj.getString("type") : null;  
 // New code starts  
 Uri uri = obj.has("url") ? Uri.parse(obj.getString("url")) : null;  
 String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(obj.getString("url"));  
 if(extension != null){  
      MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();  
      type = mimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);  
 }  
 // New code ends  
 JSONObject extras = obj.has("extras") ? obj.getJSONObject("extras") : null;
```